# How to setup a common debug window in ionic/angularjs

Tags: angularjs, debugging, ionic-framework

I would like to have a place to put common debug information while developing an ionic app. The main reason is to have a common place for the debug info an not have to look around for this info in platform specific places. So whether I'm in an iOS or Androis emulator I can see the debug info in the same place.

I have added a "debug" page in the side menu for this purpose. I am having difficulting figuring out how to add information to this page from different places (i.e. start page, deail page etc.) in the app.

I have a template "debug.html" with a div container, where I would like to add the debug info.

How do I add the info to the div container in the "debug.html" from anywhere in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a service which would hold an array of debug information and display that information in your debug.html template. A quick example:

```
app.service('debug', function(){
  this.messages = [];
  this.add = function(message){
    this.messages.push(message);
  }
});
```

And in your template:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in debug.messages">{{message}}</div>
```

of course, inject the service in the template controller:

```
app.controller('debugController', function(debug) {
  this.debug = debug;
});
```

So in, for example, start page, you could add debug info like this:

```
app.controller('startPageController', function(debug, ...){
    debug.add("Start page controller initiated.");
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works well. I did have to tweak one thing, though. in the template I added "tracked by $index" to prevent a "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed" error. 

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes

Comment: @cw24 Glad I helped, this was just a quick example, although it's "track by" instead of "tracked by"